# show a message as ajax submits a form

Tags: jquery, ajax, progress-bar

Am submitting a form using this code

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET', 
    data:fields,
    url:'new/addcomm.php',
    success:function(feedback){
        reload();
        // alert (feedback);
    }
});
```

Now. How do I show the please wait gif while the ajax is submitting the form assuming I want it showing in

```
<div id="working"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at ajaxStart() and ajaxStop()? https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: I had not but now I have. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="working"><img src="loader.gif" style="display:none;"/></div>


$.ajax({
    type:'GET', 
    data:fields,
    url:'new/addcomm.php',
    beforeSend: function(){
       $('#working img').show();  
    }, 
    complete:function(){
       $('#working img').hide();     
    },
    success:function(feedback){
        reload();
        // alert (feedback);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @think different

Answer (score 2):

To use `beforeSend`  and `complete` settings of ajax.
**[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET', 
    data:fields,
    url:'new/addcomm.php',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#working').show();
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#working').hide();
    },
    success:function(feedback){
        reload();
        // alert (feedback);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajaxStart and ajaxStop like this

```
//show image when clicks on submit button
$('form').ajaxStart(function() {
  $('#working').show();
});

//hide image when ajax request stop
$('form').ajaxStop(function() {
  $('#working').hide();
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its working but doing the opposite of what its supposed to do. The div shows by default and hides while jquery is working. Anyway, Ave used the beforesend method. Thanks @lalitharyani

Answer (score 0):

Here is how

HTML

```
<div id="working"><img src="loader.gif"/></div>
```

CSS

```
#working { display: none; }
```

JS:

```
var $loader = $('#working');
$loader.show();
$.ajax({
    type:'GET', 
    data:fields,
    url:'new/addcomm.php',
    success:function(feedback){
        reload();
        $loader.hide(); //or .fadeOut();
    }
});
```

OR try beforeSend

```
var $loader = $('#working');
$.ajax({
    type:'GET', 
    data:fields,
    url:'new/addcomm.php',
    beforeSend: function(){
       $loader.show();
    },
    success:function(feedback){
        reload();
        $loader.hide(); //or .fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Aamir . Your code is almost similar to the one before. Thanks, thanks